# PHP forms getting $_POST as $key => $value, for value that is an array

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a multiselect checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myfood" name="myfood" value="Cheese">
<input type="checkbox" id="myfood" name="myfood" value="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" id="myfood" name="myfood" value="Beef">
<input type="checkbox" id="myfood" name="myfood" value="Salad">
```

I would like to select all 4.

I'm currently using :

```
$post_fields = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
      $post_fields[$key] =  $value;
}
```

The snippet above only produces the last item : Salad
I'm specifically asked to use that ID, so I cannot change the IDs or the Names = 'myfood'.
*edited

How can I edit the code so that I get : Cheese, Apple, Beef, Salad

- I also have other fields like "your name" that is not an array.

Please help!

Comment: `name="myfood[]"`

Comment: As you are using the same `name="myfood"` on multiple inputs, it needs to be an array as @u_mulder says above

Comment: thanks for your answers.
I forgot to write that name value must also not change. :(